# Change the properties of a <div> with <select> options with jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, html-select

I want to change the visibility of divs depending on the option selected in a dropdown menu, I thought something like this would work

```
<select>
<option onclick="hideButton();" value="A">A</option>
<option onclick="showButton();" value="B">B</option>
<option onclick="showButton();" value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

I have one button that I want to change the visibility of

```
<input class="button" name="button" type="submit" value="delete" />

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function hideButton(){$(".button").hide("slow");}
function showButton(){$(".button").show("slow");} 
</script>
```

of course it does nothing and I've no idea why, I thought the theory was sound but I just don't know enough about jquery

Comment: `<div>` or `<input ... />`?. `$(".button").hide("slow");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  $('select').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'A'){
      hideButton();
    }else{
      showButton();
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

[Check FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/t3Rbv/1/)

```
    $(function() {
        $('select').on('change', function() {

            if ($(this).val() == 'A') {
                $('.button').hide('slow');
            }
            else {
                $('.button').show('slow');
            }
        }).change();
    });​

<select>
<option value="A">A</option>
<option value="B">B</option>
<option value="C">C</option>
</select>
<input class="button" name="button" type="submit" value="delete" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can decide on the `option` that action has to take:

Html:

```
<select>
   <option data-visibility="hide" value="A">A</option>
   <option data-visibility="show" value="B">B</option>
   <option data-visibility="show" value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

Js (jQuery):

```
$('select').bind('change', function(event) {

    var method = $(this).find('option:selected').data('visibility');
    $('.button')[method]('slow');

});
```